# Click function jquery not working

Tags: jquery, laravel

I use tab bootstrap component like this

```
<header class="card-header">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a id="show" data-show="published" class="nav-link {{ request()->show == null || request()->show == 'published' ? 'active' : '' }}">Semua</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a id="show" data-show="draft" class="nav-link {{ request()->show == 'draft' ? 'active' : '' }}">Draft</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a id="show" data-show="pending" class="nav-link {{ request()->show == 'pending' ? 'active' : '' }}">Pending</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </header>
```

And i handle when `<a id="show"></a>` click then redirect to different link

```
$("#show").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location =  updateURLParameter(window.location.href, "show", $(this).attr("data-show"));
   });
```

But the browser not redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest this way

```
$("body #show").click(function(e) {
    console.log("It so ok");
    #your code
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :), but the question solved bg $("a#show").click()

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
$("#show").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location = '/data-show';
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :), but the question solved bg $("a#show").click()

Answer (score 0):

The jquery selector has to be `$("[id='idOfElement']")` format.

So use:

```
$("[id='show']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location =  updateURLParameter(window.location.href, "show", 
$(this).attr("data-show"));
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :), but the question solved bg $("a#show").click()

Answer (score 0):

Because you use **id**, **An id should be unique within a page, so you should use the #id selector when you want to find a single, unique element**.I recommend switching to class,

```
$(".nav-item a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location =  updateURLParameter(window.location.href, "show", $(this).attr("data-show"));
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :), but the question solved bg $("a#show").click()

Comment: i think use class is better